# how to managed if else condition in unit test Angular

Tags: sonarqube-scan

how to handle if else condition in test spec.
it is giving 60% coverage in sonarqube due to this if condition.
sonarqube giving if path not taken error

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginService} from "../service/login.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let a="test";
    if (a==""){
      this.getName();
    }
    else{
      alert("name already fetched");
    }
  
  }
  getName(){
    return "pp";
  }
}

test spec code for above code

   it('should call getName if a is empty', () => {
    let a="";
    component.getName();
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.getName()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(a).toEqual("");
});
```